# How do I calculate the max of subsets over a range and set all cells to it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table with data that looks like:

```
Col 1   Col 2
14795   11691357
14796   11691361
14796   11691363
14811   11695431
14811   11695433
14796   11695443
14796   11695444
14796   11695455
14796   11695472
14813   11696837
14813   11696839
14814   11696853
14814   11696855
```

How do I search through Col 1 and for any that are the same, such as 14814, do a Max() on the corresponding Col 2.  Then, once I have the max, I need to go back and set the other rows to be that max in Col 2.

So for example, we'll use 14814 for Col 1.  The max in Col 2 is then 11696855.  Then I need to go back and set 11696853 to be 11696855.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you'll have to use VBA for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using worksheet formulas. To automate this task you will need a VBA-based solution.

Here is a small routine that will do it. Place this routine in a standard code module:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim i&, j&, m#, s$, u, v
    v = [A1].CurrentRegion.Resize(, 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If InStr(s, "|" & v(i, 1)) = 0 Then s = s & "|" & v(i, 1)
    Next
    u = Split(s, "|")
    For j = 1 To UBound(u)
        m = -1.79769313486231E+308 '<-- most negative number recognized
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            If v(i, 1) = Val(u(j)) Then
                If m < v(i, 2) Then m = v(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            If v(i, 1) = Val(u(j)) Then
                v(i, 2) = m
            End If
        Next
    Next
    [D1:E1].Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```

Then on the worksheet where you want the work done, press ALT-F8 to open the Macro Dialog.

Run the Demo macro.

That's it.

**IMPORTANT**

-The routine assumes that the data will be in columns A and B.

-To prevent data loss, the routine outputs the results to columns D and E. So make sure columns D and E are blank before you run this.

-You can easily edit the input and output columns by replacing what is in the square brackets, [ ], at the beginning and the end of the routine.